# Searching for a string variable with jquery inarray() returns -1

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

I'm trying to search for a string in an array. If that string matches, I want to know which index number in that array has the matching string. I believe I should be using inArray(); but it's always returning -1

```
var $eventwrap = $j('.tw-events'),
    $daywrap = $j('.tw-day'),
    $dayfilter = $j('#tw-filter-days li a');
    $daywraphide = $j('tw-day.hide'),
    $catwrap = $j('.tw-event-filter'),
    $viewctrls = $j('.tw-view a'),

    // RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE

    $clonedays = $j('.select-days').html(),
    $clonebarrio = $j('.select-barrio').html(),
    $clonecats = $j('.select-cats').html(),
    $opday = $clonedays.split("</option>"),
    $opbarrio = $clonebarrio.split("</option>"),
    $opcategory = $clonecats.split("</option>");

    // RELEVANT CODE ENDS HERE

    filters = {};


// CHECK IF A GIVEN DAY HAS EVENTS
function filterToggle(element,x,y) {
    $j(element).each(function(){
        var $me = $j(this),
            isli = $me.is('li');
        if(isli) {
            var myvalue = $me.find('a').attr('data-filter');
        } else {
            // RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE

            var myselect = $me.parent().attr('data-filter-group'),
                myvalue = $me.attr('data-filter'),
                myfilter = String(myvalue);

            // RELEVANT CODE ENDS HERE

        }

        if(!x) {x = ''}
        if(!y) {y = ''}

        var eventcount = $j('.tw-event'+ myvalue + x + y).length;

        if(eventcount == 0) {
            if(isli) {
                $me.addClass('empty tdn');
            } else {
                $me.remove();
            }
        } else {
            if(isli) {
                $me.removeClass('empty tdn');
            } else {

            // RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE

                var myarray = eval("(" + '$op' + myselect + ")");

                alert($j.inArray(myfilter,myarray));
            // RELEVANT CODE ENDS HERE
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i don't understand... please explain... i was trying to convert a string into an object

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: ok thanks for the tip... what's the alternative to turn that string into an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not help you solve your original question about inArray() returning -1, but I wanted to shed some light on the issues the other users had pointed out.

### Alternatives to  `eval()`

- If your $op* variables exist in global scope you could use the window object and access them from there:

  ```
   var myArray = window['$op' + myselect];
  ```
- Better yet, you can remove your variables from global scope by placing them in a module.  Maybe try something like this:

  ```
  var myNamespace = (function() {
    var $eventwrap = $j('.tw-events'),
    $daywrap = $j('.tw-day'),
    $dayfilter = $j('#tw-filter-days li a'),

       ...

    $opday = $clonedays.split("</option>"),
    $opbarrio = $clonebarrio.split("</option>"),
    $opcategory = $clonecats.split("</option>");

    return {
      opday: $opday,
      opbarrio: $opbarrio,
          ...
      //whatever you need to access externally goes in the return object
    }

  })();

  //Now you can access these variables like so
  function filterToggle(element,x,y) {
      ...
     var myarray = myNamespace['$op' + myselect];
      ...
  }
  ```

### Variable Declarations

Javascript is function-level scoped; not blocked-level scoped. In block-level scoped languages variables declared inside a conditional block are local to that block. In JavaScript this is not the case, and you can run into some strange behavior, such as variable hoisting.  I'm not going in to detail on JavaScript scoping, as this post is already getting too long, but [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) awesome article does a great job explaining it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do by looking at your code but I think the whole approach is kinda weird and [WET](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131180/what-is-the-meaning-of-wet-code), I would probably rethink the whole thing. You have some *serious* syntax errors; many misplaced `;` in your `var` declarations. It's also not a good idea to declare variables inside conditional blocks. From jslint --> `eval === evil`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayString = new Array();
        var string = "this is the data to insert in array";
        arrayString = string.split(" ");
        //checking for data in above array
        $.each(arrayString, function(i, val) {
            alert(arrayString[i]);
            if (arrayString[i] == "data") {
                alert(i);//i gives the index of the found element
            }

        });
```

Comment: I hope you are looking for this. It just finds the word data from the given array and displays its index when it finds data